# communicator 2005 automation api?

Tags: .net

i am all new to .Net .I am interested in writing an application in C#/VB/VB.net that will send the messages to all online peoples.
I found The  OFFICE Communicator api ,but unable to run the code that i found from MSDN site ( although code was for  communicator 2007). 
did anyone did it before for Communicator 2005 ,please help me.

thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Link to Office Communicator 2005 Automation API and sample code:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=02ff5eaa-7f13-4670-90ad-9ed3719d1730&displaylang=en